# DECODE in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I don't quite understand how this DECODE function will resolve itself, specifically in the pointed (==>) parameter:

```
DECODE
(
    SH.RESPCODE, 0, SH.AMOUNT-DEVICE_FEE,
    102, SH.NEW_AMOUNT-DEVICE_FEE,
    ==>AMOUNT-DEVICE_FEE,
    0
)
```

Thanks in advance for any enlightenment on what that parameter will resolve to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pseudo-code, this would be equivalent to the following IF statement

```
IF( sh.respcode = 0 )
THEN
  RETURN sh.amount-device_fee
ELSIF( sh.respcode = 102 )
THEN
  RETURN sh.new_amount-device_fee
ELSIF( sh.respcode = amount-device_fee )
THEN
  RETURN 0;
END IF;
```

Answer (score 3):

It says:

```
If the value of SH.RESPCODE is 0, then return SH.AMOUNT-DEVICE_FEE.
Otherwise, if it's equal to 102, then return SH.NEW_AMOUNT-DEVICE_FEE.
Otherwise, if it's equal to AMOUNT-DEVICE_FEE, then return 0
```

As a case statement it would be:

```
Case SH.RESPCODE
  when 0                 then SH.AMOUNT-DEVICE_FEE
  when 102               then rSH.NEW_AMOUNT-DEVICE_FEE
  when AMOUNT-DEVICE_FEE then 0
  else null
end
```

There are some subtle differences with respect to treatment of NULL between the two.

Answer (score 1):

`DECODE` is basically equivalent to a `CASE` expression.

So this

```
DECODE
(
    SH.RESPCODE, 0, SH.AMOUNT-DEVICE_FEE,
    102, SH.NEW_AMOUNT-DEVICE_FEE,
    ==>AMOUNT-DEVICE_FEE,
    0
)
```

is equivalent to this

```
CASE SH.RESPCODE
    WHEN 0 THEN SH.AMOUNT - DEVICE_FEE
    WHEN 102 THEN SH.NEW_AMOUNT - DEVICE_FEE
    WHEN AMOUNT - DEVICE_FEE THEN 0
END
```

Comment: Yes. In other words, if `SH.RESPCODE` equals to `(AMOUNT - DEVICE_FEE)` then the expression will return `0`.

Comment: Unless, of course, one of the prior `WHEN` clauses is true. They are evaluated in order, just like the `DECODE` call.

Answer (score 0):

The comments about `DECODE` being equivalent to `CASE` are good. One thing I've found to be helpful is to format the `DECODE` call to make it more readable, as in:

```
DECODE(SH.RESPCODE,
         0,                 SH.AMOUNT-DEVICE_FEE,
         102,               SH.NEW_AMOUNT-DEVICE_FEE,
         AMOUNT-DEVICE_FEE, 0)
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Yeah, this was part of my confusion as the code lacked formatting, so I ended up assuming the last value was the default value.